# Error: invalid initialization of reference of type

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling, compiler-errors

So I have classes `Sensor`, `Car`, and `Agency` where class `Agency` takes in class `Car`, and class `Car` takes in class `Sensor`. In my source file for class `Agency` I have an error for my operator[]`\ function and that says

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type Agency& from expression of type Car
  return *invtptr;
```

My `operator[]` function is supposed to be a method to index by-reference  an object of the `m_inventory` data, where it allows you to access the agency's inventory.

Here is my `operator[]` function:

```
Agency &Agency::operator[](int index) {
    Car *invtptr = this->m_inventory;
    if (index < 0 || index > 5) {
        cout << "Array is out of bounds, exiting";
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            invtptr++;
        }   
    }
    return *invtptr;
}
```

and here are the private members from my header file for class car:

```
private:
        char m_make[256], m_model[256], m_owner[256];   
        int m_year, m_sensoramnt;
        Sensor m_sensor[3];
        float m_baseprice, m_finalprice;
        bool m_available;
```

and here are the private members from my header file for class Agency:

```
private:
        char m_name[256];
        int m_zipcode[5];
        Car m_inventory[5];
```

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: `else { return invtptr[index]; }`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that m_inventory is an array of 5 Cars. You are logging an error if index is less than 0 (good) or greater than 5. This means values you are allowing are {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. 5 is out of bounds though

Comment: A note about `zipcode`. Life will be easier on you if you use an array of `char`. You won't have to worry about some wiseguy entering 4 billion for one of the digits. Of course you will have to make sure the user's not Canadian and entering letters, but that's what `isdigit` is for. Since `zipcode` is a string of digits rather than an honest-to-gosh number, a string makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your return type. Look at the function protoype:

```
Agency &Agency::operator[](int index);
```

This expects you to return an `Agent`, but you are returning a Car. See excerpts from you code:

```
Car *invtptr = this->m_inventory;
...
return *invtptr;
```

You need to change your function to:

```
Car& Agency::operator[](int index);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to initialize a reference of type `Agency&` (in the function return) from an expression of type `Car` (which is the type of `*invtptr`).